# error in implementation of interval heap

Tags: c++, heap

i am trying to implement interval  heap,but  at the begining of describe code,i have some bugs

here it is

```
  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T> class IntervalHeap;
template <class T>
class TwoElement
{
    friend  class IntervalHeap <T>;
public:
    T left,
        right;
    };
template<class T>
class IntervalHeap
{
public:
    IntervalHeap(int heapsize=10);
    ~IntervalHeap(){delete[] heap;}
    int size()const { return currentsize;}
    T min(){
         if (currentsize==0)
             throw OutOfBounds();
          return heap[1].left;
    }
    T max() { if(currentsize==0)
         throw OutOfBounds();
    return heap[1].right;
    }
    IntervalHeap<T>& Insert(const T& x);
    IntervalHeap<T>& DeleteMin(T& x);
    IntervalHeap<T>& DeleteMax(T& x);



private:
    int currentsize;//number of elemnts in heap
    int Maxsize;//max elements permited
    TwoElement<T>*heap;//element  array


};
int main(){



    return 0;
}
```

after compile code,it compiles fine

```
1>------ Build started: Project: interval_heap, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  interval_heap.cpp
1>  interval_heap.vcxproj -> c:\users\daviti\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\interval_heap\Debug\interval_heap.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

but problem is that  at the writing code like this heap[1].left it show me No members avialable

Answer (score 2):

This one:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T> class IntervalHeap; // forward declaration

template <class T>
class TwoElement
{
    friend  class IntervalHeap<T>; // the "class" was missing
public:
    T left,right;
};

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

at least compiles.

I added a forward declaration of your class `IntervalHead<T>` and the keyword **class** int the friend declaration.

Comment: why we need twice  declaration of IntervalHeap?

Comment: hmmm. The friend declaration declares _something_ (e.g. a class) as friend, but it does not declare the class. In other words: the class IntervalHeap must be known before you can make it a friend. (Language lawyers might kill me now).

Comment: but i can't access  elements of TwoElements by friend class why?

Comment: show the access code. The TwoElements class must be known, where you want to access it (within IntervalHeap). If it's in another compiler unit (another cpp file), than that may be the problem.

Comment: i will update ok my code,when i run ,it compiles,but  by execution code like  this  heap[1].left  it show me at the bottom of compilator that no members found,i will show  my total code at the moment

Comment: code compiles @Jörg Beyer  but if  you  copy this code and past into you  compiler,please  for a one second delete this line  heap[1].left and write again ,aim is that when you type heap[1]. it notices you that no Members found,so i am interested why it is so?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8362/discussion-between-jorg-beyer-and-dato)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `friend class IntervalHeap<T>`?

`friend` on its own is used for declaring a friend function.